# Error: assignment to '_List_iterator<unsigned int,unsigned int &,unsigned int *>' from 'int'

Tags: c++, list, logging, stl, iterator

I'm trying to implement a list which will store relevant indices.
However I get an error at `for (index_itr = (list_size - numberOfEvents  - 1)` mentioned in the title. What mistake am I doing, and how to correct it?

```
void logPrintEntry(UINT32 index, UINT32 portID, UINT16 numberOfEvents)
{
    LOG_ENTRY log;
    list <UINT32> list_telnet_indices;
    log = (pLOG_ENTRY) &(Data.Log.log[index]);
    list <UINT32> ::iterator index_itr;
    UINT16 list_size = list_telnet_indices.size();
    if( list_size <= numberOfEvents )
    {
        // print all logs
        for ( index_itr = list_telnet_indices.begin();
            index_itr != list_telnet_indices.end(); ++index_itr )
        {
            printDataOnly(log, *index_itr, portID);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // print only the last relevant entries
        for (index_itr = (list_size - numberOfEvents  - 1);     //error: assignment to '_List_iterator<unsigned int,unsigned int &,unsigned int *>' from 'int'
        index_itr != list_telnet_indices.end(); ++index_itr)
        {
            printDataOnly(log, *index_itr, portID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index_itr` is an iterator, `list_size - numberOfEvents - 1` is an integer. Those are not compatible.

Use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) to set iterator of `std::list`

```
#include <iterator>     // std::advance

index_itr = list_telnet_indices.begin();
std::advance(index_itr, list_size - numberOfEvents - 1);
for (; index_itr != list_telnet_indices.end(); ++index_itr)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: i've taken the freedom to merge our two answers. You give a suitable solution and I explained the error. I think this answer will get more attention this way.